# AsyncTask doInBackground() does not execute correctly on run, but works on debugger

Tags: arraylist

```
@Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> PLIST = new ArrayList<>();
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(jsonUrl);
        ArrayList<String> URLList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            placesList.clear();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray placesJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
                String pToken = "";

                // looping through All Places
                for (int i = 0; i < placesJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject placesJSONObject = placesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = placesJSONObject.getString("id");
                    String name = placesJSONObject.getString("name");

                    HashMap<String, String> places = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    places.put("id", id);
                    places.put("name", name);

                    PLIST.add(places);
                }

                //TODO: fix this...
                if (SEARCH_RADIUS == 1500) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "did it get to 1500?");
                    try {
                        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                            //error is no value for next_page_token... this
```

ERROR HERE

```
                            pToken = jsonObj.getString("next_page_token"); //if I place breakpoint here, debugger runs correctly, and returns more than 20 results if there is a next_page_token.
                            String newjsonUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="
                                    + midpointLocation.getLatitude() + "," + midpointLocation.getLongitude()
                                    + "&radius=" + SEARCH_RADIUS + "&key=AIzaSyCiK0Gnape_SW-53Fnva09IjEGvn55pQ8I&pagetoken=" + pToken;
                            URLList.add(newjsonUrl);

                            jsonObj = new JSONObject(new HttpHandler().makeServiceCall(newjsonUrl)); //moved

                            Log.e(TAG, "page does this try catch");
                            }
                        }

                    catch (Exception e ) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "page token not found: " + e.toString());
                    }
                    for (String url : URLList){
                        Log.e(TAG, "url is : " + url);
                    }
```

I made an ArrayList of URLS after many attempts to debug this code, I planned on unpacking the ArrayList after all the urls with next_page_tokens were added, and then parsing through each of them later. When running the debugger with the breakpoint on pToken = getString("next_page_token") i get the first url from the Logger, and then the second url correctly. When I run as is, I get the first url, and then the following error: **JSONException: No value for next_page_token**

**Things I've tried**

Invalidating Caches and restarting

Clean Build

Run on different SDK versions

Made sure that the if statement is hitting (SEARCH_RADIUS == 1500)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Function is called in a listener function like this.

```
new GetPlaces(new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> output) {
            Log.e(TAG, "outputasync:" );
            placesList = output;
        }
    }).execute();
```

My onPostExecute method.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        delegate.processFinish(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Async Tasks in a Razor-engine rendered file... how on earth can you believe it would work? Do you await your Task anywhere?

Comment: Can you explain why I shouldn't believe it would work?

Comment: Because of async-race-conditions. Where do you call the method?

Comment: Can you await the call?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the google places api takes a few milliseconds to validate the next_page_token after it is generated. As such, I have used the wait() function to pause before creating the newly generated url based on the next_page_token. This fixed my problem. Thanks for the help.